# Regex in Notepad++ to find missing word before a string

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have some html files that I want to find them if these words:

```
id="s"
```

doesn't have this tag before them

```
<div
```

And if it doesn't, the regex adds it, so the result be:

```
<div id="s"
```

And leaves everything before the div or after id="s" as is.

Given that:

- the id="s" could have spaces or tabs before it
- it has some words after it
- the missing "< div" could be before it with a line or in the same line before the id="s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to search for all occurrences of either `<div id="s"` or `id="s"` that follows any whitespace and replace either one with `<div id="s"`.  (That is, rather than looking for `id="s"` then looking backwards for `<div`, just include `<div` in the search.)

Find what: `<div\s*id="s"|\s*id="s"`
Replace with: `<div id="s"`

Before:

```
test
test <div
id="s"
test
id="s"
test <div id="s"
test    id="s"
<div    id="s"
test   id="s"
<div  id="s"
```

After Replace all:

```
test
test <div id="s"
test<div id="s"
test <div id="s"
test<div id="s"
<div id="s"
test<div id="s"
<div id="s"
```

You can either add leading whitespace to the search and replace fields, or do another pass to put however much space you need back between `test<div id="s"`.